# How can I skip the then part of a case statement in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a situation in which I need to do nothing if these conditions are met in the when part and assign value otherwise. I am using the `case when <expression> then <some operation/assignment> end` in my SQL.

I want to skip this then part as this is a special condition and I do not want any assignment here just pass by to the else

```
(case
    when '$usertype_id' = 'null' or '$usertype_id' = 0 or '$usertype_id' = 999 
       then //do nothing
    else x.usertype_id = '$usertype_id'
end)
```

Please let me know how can I achieve this. Thank you.

Comment: Things needed to help you:  What flavor of SQL.  More of the query.  valid syntax (it looks like you randomly interspersed apostrophes in the code)

Comment: @dougp sorry for that I fixed those. Thanks

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can't do assignment with `case` anyway.

Comment: Are you sure you want to check for the *varchar* text "null", instead of an 'is null' check?

Answer (score 1):

You don't.  You use conditional logic *without* a `case expression`:

```
('$usertype_id = 'null' or '$usertype_id = 0 or '$usertype_id = 999) or
(x.usertype_id = '$usertype_id')
```

More importantly, I would strongly, strongly encourage you to use parameters instead of munging query strings with parameter values.

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by ''strongly encourage you to use parameters instead of munging query strings with parameter values''. Thanks

Comment: @HarshalJani . . . You appear to be putting variables directly into query strings.  You should be using parameters instead.  The exact syntax depends on your database and application layer, but there are numerous examples around to show you how.